# How to implement curl(POST the json file) using java

Tags: java

I have a Json file(Message.json) with some data.

Now I want to run the following command using java.

```
curl -v -X POST "URL" -H 'content-type: application/json' -d @Message.json
```

I tried to start by getting the below code form google.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "curl",
        "-s",
        "http://static.tumblr.com/cszmzik/RUTlyrplz/the-simpsons-season-22-episode-13-the-blue-and-the-gray.jpg ");

    pb.directory(new File("C:\\Test") );
    pb.directory(new File("D:\\CurlOutput"));
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\CurlOutput\\");

    /*    With some other code */
}
```

But got following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl" (in directory "D:\CurlOutput"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>       at ProcessBuilderTest.main(ProcessBuilderTest.java:20)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:386)
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>       ... 6 more

I am very new to use curl command in java. Could anybody please provide some code for the scenario mentioned at the top.

Comment: I would not recommend using a shell command from within Java. Use the standard Java library with HTTP POST for this!

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the data using HttpGet. But i am not able to post the json data. I have to POST the following json data. I do not know how to post json array further contains nested array.
[
  {
    "type": "Message",
    "host": "abc.com",
    "data": {
      "Guid": "bc10-07d2ba",
      "messageTime": "2015-04-28",
      "hashedRecipients": [
        "f965@any.com",
      ],
      "uris": [
        "http://hjfgdsf.com/jsdfjhbd"   
      ],
      "qid": "uiwdiegfdweg",
      "classification": [
        "HHHH"
      ],
      "publishedType": "MKSKOSKSAO"
    }
  }
]

Comment: Try e.g. http://square.github.io/retrofit/ or http://square.github.io/okhttp/ It's easy to use and will perfectly work as java replacement of curl.